# How can I "freeze" a collectionView where it is?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make it so that when the user swipes to reload in a collectionView it will "freeze"the cells where they are while I perform an animation. As in: when the reload happens they are 80px away from the left side, so they should stay there.

**How can I do this?**

Research: I have not been able to find anything regarding this.

I have tried the following and failed:

```
//            collectionView.bounces = false
//            collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

### Update:

**An idea I have been contemplating is to do the following.**

Add a Cell which is all white so it looks like it is not there. It would be a temporary cell. Then as soon as the updating is complete remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the snapshot view of your collection view and use it for animation.

```
let snapshotView = collectionView?.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)
```

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview)

Comment: @NCT127 how about snap shot view? I updated my answer.

Comment: this seems like a bad fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

Comment: Clarify the problem statement a bit more.